# How does SQL Server system check duplicates?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I definitely know how to check duplicates/remove duplicates using SQL Server queries. But I am asking a deeper question about the system.

How does the system handle duplicates? For example, how does the system remove duplicates from `UNION ALL` to `UNION`? I am guessing if the system is using hash code to do so?

The employer said the process has something to do with `ROWID`. But even if two rows are exactly the same, their `ROWID` should be different, correct? How is that possible?

Comment: This is the question I was asked during an interview

Comment: Query execution plan will tell you a story: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/sql/performance/execution-plan-basics/

Comment: In 30 years of working on sql server its not a question that's ever come up. Stupid interview question I'd say. Someone trying to prove how smart they are I think. Dosn't have anything to do with ROWID. UNION will have result set unique over the columns specified, if you included ROWID then UNION and UNION ALL would be the same result as the ROWID is unique

Answer (score 1):

How SQL Server currently *seems* to do it (this is, after all, an implementation detail that you shouldn't worry about) is that it will temporarily *sort* the output rows. It doesn't matter what sort ordering it picks, so long as it picks one<sup>1</sup>.

Then it iterates over these sorted output rows, remembering the last row it emitted. If the current row is equal, in all columns, to the last emitted row, then that row itself is not emitted.

Since it's not defined what sort order it will choose, nor whether it will apply other tricks (such as *partitioning* the result data across some columns and then sorting each partition independently/in parallel), you should not *assume* the the output will be sorted, unless you've also applied a specific `ORDER BY` clause.

There is no `ROWID` in SQL Server.

---

<sup>1</sup>It does need to be based on all columns, however. Basically, we're working so that duplicate rows end up in consecutive rows.

Comment: Sometimes it sorts and sometimes it hashes.  It depends which it thinks will be faster and/or whether the sort can be re-used elsewhere in the query.

Comment: When you said there is no RowID in SQL Server, how about Index? They are highly related to RowID in SQL Server.